# How to put helper methods and private methods in helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some helpers and private methods in a controller, and I want to have the same helpers and private methods in another controller. So I moved that code to module and tried to include the module in the second controller. But I can't seem to do it, because it says undefined method helper method for the DashboardHelper. Is there anyway to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Here is the code

```
module DashboardHelper
    def get_date(log)

  end


  def get_working_hours(log)

  end


  helper_method :get_date, :get_working_hours 


  private
  def employee_params

  end

  def identify_employee

  end

  def check_is_arrived 

  end

  def calculate_time_percentage

  end


end

class AccountController < ApplicationController
  include DashboardHelper
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello gates you have to include `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` in your concern .
This should not be in your helper folder instead pull it somewhere in you concern folder

the end file may look like

```
module DashboardHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def get_date(log)
    end


   def get_working_hours(log)
   end

   helper_method :get_date, :get_working_hours 

   private
   def employee_params

   end

   def identify_employee
   end

   def check_is_arrived 
   end

   def calculate_time_percentage
   end

  end
end
```